# Vue.js check if scroller scrolled to the element

Tags: vue.js

I have an element in my html code

```
<div class="my_div">
</div>
```

Now i want to `alert` when user scrolled to this element.How can i do that using Vue considering that `my_div` is in the center of the page?

Comment: I don't think vuejs provides any API for this function, but there're various ways to achieve this. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/487073/check-if-element-is-visible-after-scrolling

Answer (score 0):

You should use the vue $ref.

HTML

```
<div id="PAGE-MAIN-PARENT-DIV" v-scroll="handleScroll">
  <div ref="my_div" > </div>
</div>
```

JS

```
Vue.directive('scroll', {
  inserted: function (el, binding) {
    let f = function (evt) {
      if (binding.value(evt, el)) {
        window.removeEventListener('scroll', f)
      }
    }
    window.addEventListener('scroll', f)
  }
})
```

Inside Vue methods:

```
methods: {
    handleScroll (evt, el) {
      if (!this.$refs.my_div) {
        return false
      }

      const emissionYOfsset = this.$refs.my_div.$el.offsetTop

      // Change this condition in order to fit your requirements
      if (window.scrollY + window.innerHeight >= emissionYOfsset &&
        window.scrollY <= emissionYOfsset) {
        console.log('currently in screen')

        // Do you want to continue with the event?
        return false
      }
    }
  }
```